# What is POF in networking?

Tags: networking

I was reading some academic articles about networking when I read "protocol oblivious forwarding (POF)" which I tried to google it but I got nothing to simplify it.

Please, what is protocol oblivious forwarding (POF)? And dose it relate to Programming Protocol-Independent Packet Processors (P4)?

Comment: I personally have never heard of this term. It could be useful if you could link to these articles to provide some context.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHWL_enIQ865IQ865&biw=1366&bih=657&ei=W1uFXdybC82jwALAqZqwDw&q=what+is+protocol+oblivious+forwarding+in+networking&oq=what+is+protocol+oblivious+forwarding+in+networking&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30.177394.184900..185530...0.0..0.191.2674.0j16......0....1..gws-wiz.......33i160j33i10.oPEQ-4MTV8c&ved=0ahUKEwictfDpweDkAhXNEVAKHcCUBvYQ4dUDCAs&uact=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POF  is a flexible and programmable forwarding plane i that help in the essential to maximize the value of Software-Defined Networks (SDN). The forwarding plane becomes protocol-independent and can be reprogrammed to support new protocol stacks seamlessly.

Comment: How does it differ from P4?

Answer (score 2):

[P4](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2656877.2656890) and [POF](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2491185.2491190) are domain-specific languages for programmable networks. Both languages allow the network developer to program the network introducing custom protocols and even [advanced telemetry](https://nkatta.github.io/papers/int-hula.pdf), something not possible in the past.

The main difference between POF and P4 is the packet parsing process. In P4 the packet parser is represented as a finite state machine wherein POF the packet parser is expressed as <start, offset> key-pairs. Both languages define a set of permitted operations (additions, shifts etc.), the match+action table pipeline, how the data plane and control plane can communicate, and what information they can exchange.

I strongly advise you to read the scientific papers I included since they describe in detail the two languages.

Hope I helped!